# Orthogonal Projection on hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I found this exercise on a book, I guess it's not hard but don't know what to do.

> Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and let $P:H \rightarrow H$ be linear. If $P$ is a projection, i.e $P^2 =P$, and $\langle Px,y\rangle=\langle x,Py\rangle$ then $P$ is an orthogonal projection.

Comment: This extra condition says $P=P^*$. So $\mbox{Im }P^\perp=\mbox{Ker }P^*=\mbox{Ker }P$.

Comment: A LaTeX tip: `<` and `>` mean "less than" and "greater than", and produce spacing correct for *that meaning only*. When you want angle brackets, you need to use `\langle` and `\rangle`. You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful.